Fix HTML Autoplay issue. Does not work with JS or when muted attribute is applied

I've been trying to add background music to my website for months now, it used to work using an iframe and embed YouTube but that doesn't autoplay anymore.
I've been looking up this issue all morning but no avail. It only starts working when the user interacts with it, which is undesirable in my case.
All solutions have boiled down to muting the audio then making it play with JavaScript.
Here is the code below:
<audio controls autoplay muted>
    <source src ="audio.mp3">
</audio>

<script>
  var audio = document.querySelector("audio");
  audio.muted = true;
  audio.play(); 
  audio.muted = false;
</script>

I tried many variations of this, like not trying to play with JavaScript, but only by unmuting the sound.
<audio controls autoplay muted>
    <source src ="audio.mp3">
</audio>

<script>
  audio.muted = false;
</script>

I have tried multiple different things, yet I cannot get the audio to autoplay. No matter what I try. How can I solve this issue?

You can't bypass this. Possible duplicate of Auto-play video/audio blocked in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

As others already pointed out you MUST have a first user interaction on your page to play audio content.

Maybe you can check getAutoplayPolicy()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getAutoplayPolicy
And I think always this can be a way:
function PlayMusic() {

  var play=document.getElementById("music");
  play.play();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(PlayMusic,3000);
})


It still says user interaction is needed. Also the getAutoplayPolicy() seems to only let me know when I can or not use autoplay.
